# AnimatedExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I use [idunnololz](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView) lib for animate expandable list. My child view has border, that i've maden using ninepatch format as view background. When expandable list start animate my bottom border disappeared, but my right and left border still visible. When animation finished, my bottom border set visible. Why my bottom border doesn't draw with other elements of view ? Also in this library, author redrawing divider every time, cause it also has such effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to proper override onLayout method in DummyView.
Correct variant:

```
for(int i = 0; i < views.size; i++) { 
   View v = views.get(i);
   top = i*v.getMeasuredHeight();
   v.layout(left, top, v.getMeasuredWidth(), top + v.getMeasuredHeight());
}
```